# Intellij not recognizing test annotation

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

IntelliJ is not recognizing my @Test annotation in the IDE. I'm able to run my tests just fine using the IDE and command line. However, I am not able to remove the red, squiggly error line underneath "@Test"

The error message says "'@Test' not applicable to method"...but it should be, especially if the tests run.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Version: Intellij IDEA 15.0.6

Error Image

[image: Screenshot]

My POM.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>javaForTesters</groupId>
<artifactId>javaForTesters</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the maven projects view, try to reimport all maven modules. Check the settings in *Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / maven / Importing*, you might want to set the import to automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if reimport not work.Try compile and package your code from command line  ,execute command  'mvn clean package -Pyouprofile' to see the corresponding information.